# Something strange happening when assigning title to UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am having some viewControllers each connected by segues. The rootViewController is connected to the NavigationController. Now, in one UIViewController, I am performing a segue to go to another UIViewController like this and it works:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toLoginTypeActivity", sender: self)
```

The UIViewController to which I am taken to after the segues is performed is this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class LoginTypeActivityViewController: UIViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        println("I am here.")
        //self.title = "Namaskar"         // Here seems to be something strange.
        println("I am here also.")
    }
}
```

But, the segue does not work if I comment out `self.title` in the code(marked as strange). Though, all the println are working. Even, "I am here also." gets printed. But, the segues is not getting performed. It gives a runtime error.

What should be the problem and how should it be resolved? I am sure I have named the identifier correctly.

Here is the runtime error:

```
2014-10-13 17:21:27.878 mobilepay[29387:1382271] -[Swift._NSContiguousString set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b6b33d0
2014-10-13 17:21:27.881 mobilepay[29387:1382271] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Swift._NSContiguousString set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b6b33d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00bb5df6 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0083fa97 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00bbda75 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00b069c7 ___forwarding___ + 1047
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00b0658e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   UIFoundation                        0x067eeb91 __NSStringDrawingEngine + 29221
6   UIFoundation                        0x067e784d -[NSString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) drawWithRect:options:attributes:context:] + 171
7   UIKit                               0x013be151 -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:] + 6626
8   UIKit                               0x013bbe30 -[UILabel drawTextInRect:] + 581
9   UIKit                               0x013be256 -[UILabel drawRect:] + 98
10  UIKit                               0x0123354b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 519
11  QuartzCore                          0x01077d51 -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 118
12  QuartzCore                          0x01077c87 _ZL16backing_callbackP9CGContextPv + 96
13  QuartzCore                          0x00f5c7ae CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 2788
14  QuartzCore                          0x01077c1f ___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke + 93
15  QuartzCore                          0x010ad406 x_blame_allocations + 15
16  QuartzCore                          0x01077a85 _ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev + 1591
17  QuartzCore                          0x01077cd6 -[CALayer _display] + 33
18  QuartzCore                          0x01077446 _ZN2CA5Layer7displayEv + 142
19  QuartzCore                          0x01077cb0 -[CALayer display] + 33
20  QuartzCore                          0x0106bee6 _ZN2CA5Layer17display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 322
21  QuartzCore                          0x0106bf6c _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 38
22  QuartzCore                          0x00fca676 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 284
23  QuartzCore                          0x00fcba3c _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 392
24  QuartzCore                          0x00fcc108 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
25  CoreFoundation                      0x00ad8fbe __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
26  CoreFoundation                      0x00ad8f00 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 400
27  CoreFoundation                      0x00ace93a __CFRunLoopRun + 1226
28  CoreFoundation                      0x00ace1ab CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
29  CoreFoundation                      0x00acdfdb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
30  GraphicsServices                    0x0317124f GSEventRunModal + 192
31  GraphicsServices                    0x0317108c GSEventRun + 104
32  UIKit                               0x011a8e16 UIApplicationMain + 1526
33  mobilepay                           0x001410de top_level_code + 78
34  mobilepay                           0x0014111b main + 43
35  libdyld.dylib                       0x03ad7ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Note that assigning to the `self.title` works in the other ViewControllers though.

Edit:

Here is the updated code.

```
class LoginTypeActivityViewController: UIViewController{

    var delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        println("viewDidLoad self.title = \(self.title)")
        println("viewDidLoad self.navigationItem.title = \(self.navigationItem.title)")
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        println("viewWillAppear self.title = \(self.title)")
        println("viewWillAppear self.navigationItem.title = \(self.navigationItem.title)")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        println("viewDidAppear self.title = \(self.title)")
        println("viewDidAppear self.navigationItem.title = \(self.navigationItem.title)")
        self.navigationItem.title = "Koshish"
        println("printing in viewDidAppear after setting self.navigatioItem.title = \(self.navigationItem.title)")
}
```

}

And here is the output:

```
viewDidLoad self.title = nil
viewDidLoad self.navigationItem.title = nil
viewWillAppear self.title = nil
viewWillAppear self.navigationItem.title = nil
viewDidAppear self.title = nil
viewDidAppear self.navigationItem.title = nil
printing in viewDidAppear after setting self.navigatioItem.title = Optional("Koshish")
2014-10-14 12:46:48.931 mobilepay[34547:1593230] -[Swift._NSContiguousString set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a162090
2014-10-14 12:46:48.933 mobilepay[34547:1593230] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Swift._NSContiguousString set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a162090'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00bd3df6 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0085da97 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00bdba75 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00b249c7 ___forwarding___ + 1047
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00b2458e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   UIFoundation                        0x0680cb91 __NSStringDrawingEngine + 29221
6   UIFoundation                        0x0680584d -[NSString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) drawWithRect:options:attributes:context:] + 171
7   UIKit                               0x013dc151 -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:] + 6626
8   UIKit                               0x013d9e30 -[UILabel drawTextInRect:] + 581
9   UIKit                               0x013dc256 -[UILabel drawRect:] + 98
10  UIKit                               0x0125154b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 519
11  QuartzCore                          0x01095d51 -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 118
12  QuartzCore                          0x01095c87 _ZL16backing_callbackP9CGContextPv + 96
13  QuartzCore                          0x00f7a7ae CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 2788
14  QuartzCore                          0x01095c1f ___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke + 93
15  QuartzCore                          0x010cb406 x_blame_allocations + 15
16  QuartzCore                          0x01095a85 _ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev + 1591
17  QuartzCore                          0x01095cd6 -[CALayer _display] + 33
18  QuartzCore                          0x01095446 _ZN2CA5Layer7displayEv + 142
19  QuartzCore                          0x01095cb0 -[CALayer display] + 33
20  QuartzCore                          0x01089ee6 _ZN2CA5Layer17display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 322
21  QuartzCore                          0x01089f6c _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 38
22  QuartzCore                          0x00fe8676 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 284
23  QuartzCore                          0x00fe9a3c _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 392
24  QuartzCore                          0x00fea108 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
25  CoreFoundation                      0x00af6fbe __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
26  CoreFoundation                      0x00af6f00 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 400
27  CoreFoundation                      0x00aec93a __CFRunLoopRun + 1226
28  CoreFoundation                      0x00aec1ab CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
29  CoreFoundation                      0x00aebfdb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
30  GraphicsServices                    0x0318f24f GSEventRunModal + 192
31  GraphicsServices                    0x0318f08c GSEventRun + 104
32  UIKit                               0x011c6e16 UIApplicationMain + 1526
33  mobilepay                           0x00160f5e top_level_code + 78
34  mobilepay                           0x00160f9b main + 43
35  libdyld.dylib                       0x03af5ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

### Solved

I finally found the problem in my code:

In my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I was doing this:

```
var navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
navigationBarAppearance.tintColor = UIColor(rgba: "#000000", alpha: 1.0)
navigationBarAppearance.barTintColor = UIColor(rgba: "#000000", alpha: 1.0)
navigationBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Arial-BoldMT", size: 20.0), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: "#000000", alpha: 1.0)]
```

As you can see, in NSForegroundColorAttributeName, I was just setting the string and not calling the UIColor function with it.

I feel Swift should have given me some hint that I am not calling NSForegroundColorAttribute with the correct value.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what a `PPViewController` is, and what it does behind the scenes? Replace with `UIViewController` and see if it works.

Comment: self.title is an NSString*, try to asssign @"Namaskar" instead of c style string "Namaskar".

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to change it. It does still have the same problem even after changing it to UIViewController.

Comment: The only other thing that comes to mind is that somehow the segue is occurring on a thread other than the Main thread - you can get really weird crashes when that happens. I tend to use "assert(NSThread.isMainThread())" all over my code just to be sure. I updated my answer below with more.

Comment: This line from the crash was the hint to your problem: -[NSString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) drawWithRect:options:attributes:context:] - since the attributes were improperly constructed, they were the root cause. Also, the reason Swift didn't complain when building is that it marks so many ObjC items as AnyObject. Older dictionaries just don't map into the new strict styles.

Comment: You've saved my day ! Same error with color...

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you the answer, but have suggestions on how you can solve it. Somehow the title property of your UINavigationItem is been set to some object not a NSString.

So where you have your "//self.title" line, log the value of title, the value of your class' UINavigationItem title, and if either is not nil, then log the class. My guess its somehow been set to a number not a string, but it may just be garbage or something released. Or, your storyboard file could have become corrupted.

EDIT: So something is really weird here. Other ideas:

- if this segue is triggered before viewDidLoad by the presenting view, odd things might happen.
- implement 'override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)' in the calling class, then verify you are on the main thread
- use the debugger, add an exception breakpoint, and when you get the crash verify the crash is on Thread 0. Also, poke around - there is an object that doesn't respond to a selector, you have its address, so do a 'po 0x.......' in the debugger and see what it is.
- failing that, you'll need to spend some time and attempt to create a demo project modeled after your real one, that has the same problem. If you can do that, you can upload it to a public site like Dropbox, update your question, and people like me will look at it (I'll at least do it). Its traditional if you get to this point to offer some bounty, I just say that so you know, but I'll look at it without one (I don't really need any more points).

Comment: Hi. I checked, both of the values are nil. I think I should delete and create a new storyboard. That may solve the problem. I checked the xml though, seemed alright. Not sure, though.

Comment: @Rishi the string is getting set somewhere, even if to an empty string - see the line "[Swift._NSContiguousString set]". Add two more overrides, to viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear, check to see what the title is for both your class and the navigationItem (which is probably the culprit). Even the top most line of the crash implies something is odd with the string. In fact, instead of writing self.title in viewDidLoad, try setting the navItem instead, see if that also stops the crash.

Comment: Hi David. I printed both of them in all the overrides and it still is `nil` in all of them. `viewDidLoad self.title = nil
viewDidLoad self.navigationItem.title = nil
viewWillAppear self.title = nil
viewWillAppear self.navigationItem.title = nil
viewDidAppear self.title = nil
viewDidAppear self.navigationItem.title = nil`

Comment: Also, I tried setting self.navigationItem.title in viewDidLoad but it still crashes.

Comment: I want to also tell you that after putting all the print lines and then when I tried to set the self.title/self.navigationItem.title, the print lines in viewDidAppear do not get printed. Only the print lines in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear got printed.

Comment: Also, when I set `self.navigationItem.title = "something"` in `viewDidLoad`, it sets it correctly and prints them in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` but then it crashes after that and `viewDidAppear` is never called I think.

Comment: And the app does not crash if I do not set the title. But I want to set the title.

Comment: Thanks for the help David. With break points I was able to be sure that the problem was not in the class because even after setting the value it was continuing to run. I have edited and wrote about the bug in the post.